# Solution needed to the 403 forbidden error I'm getting after deploying flask app on AWS elasticbeanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask

I need solution to the 403 error I'm getting after successfully deploying flask app on AWS elasticbeanstalk. After deploying a flask application developed in visual studio it gives 403 forbidden error. I've tried different searches to solve the problem but they haven't resolved it.

For example, it was suggested somewhere the start-off python file should be named - application.py, which I did and redeployed but it still didn't work. It was also mentioned in another example that the deployed solution was pointing to a folder instead of the start-off file, which is not the case in my situation.

Possible problems pointed at include the inability of subdomains to work with flask host or the need to make adjustment to the code below in my runserver.py for production environment of AWS.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST = environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
    try:
        PORT = int(environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
    except ValueError:
        PORT = 5555
    app.run(HOST, PORT)
```

Comment: Make sure SERVER_HOST is set, if your app only listens on localhost I don't think the load balancer will be able to route traffic to it. You may want the default to be `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: 403 is a `forbidden` permission error. If the server is only listening on localhost, the error will be a connection timeout. This error indicates that the web service is running but is not setup correctly to serve the request.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll look into them.

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggestions didn't work, however, I discovered flask applications could be served from ordinary EC2 instances so I read up on that and successfully deployed using Gunicorn and Nginx on Ubuntu. The host value of 0.0.0.0 was important though. Something else must have been wrong in my earlier trial. Anyway, glad another preferred solution worked.